# Partial derivative of a function with numpy.array input

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, derivative

I have a function like:

```
def fun(A, B, C):
    return numpy.sum(numpy.dot(A, B)) + numpy.sum(C)
```

Where A, B, C are 2-dimensional `numpy.array`, and the return value is a `float` value

How can I get the partial derivative of `fun(A,B,C)` with regard to `A`, `B`, or `c`?
 (and the partial derivatives will also be `numpy.array`)

I'm ready to use libaries like `numpy` and `scipy`, but not symbolic libraries.

Comment: For this specific function you can write the derivative by hand and implement three functions `fun_dA`, `fun_dB` and `fun_dC`. Or are you looking for a general solution for arbitrary functions `fun`?

Comment: I made simple example there, but the function i want to use is quite complex. I cannot analytically get the derivative. I want rather general solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For numerical differentiation, you can use [numdifftools](http://python.org/pypi/numdifftools).

```
import numpy as np
import numdifftools

def fun(A, B, C):
    return numpy.sum(numpy.dot(A, B)) + numpy.sum(C)

def fun_A(A, B, C):
    J = numdifftools.Jacobian(lambda z: fun(z.reshape(A.shape), B, C).ravel())
    return J(A.ravel()).reshape(A.shape)


np.random.seed(1234)
A = np.random.rand(30,30)
B = np.random.rand(30,30)
C = np.random.rand(30,30)
print fun_A(A,B,C)[3,5]
# -> 14.9081790839

# Verify result manually
Ap = A.copy()
Ap[3,5] += 1e-6
print (fun(Ap,B,C) - fun(A,B,C)) / 1e-6
# -> 14.908178855
```

You can also easily cook up your own naive numerical differention routine using the latter approach just by incrementing each matrix element at a time by a small amount.

Comment: I've tried that. It looks like it works, but extremely slow. Is there any efficient way?

Comment: This is efficient. Numerical differentiation over entries of NxN matrix unavoidably requires evaluating the function at least N^2 times --- there's no way around that. The only thing you can do is to speed up the evaluation of your function.